# DropDownListFor not binding on edit post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding, dropdownlistfor

I am trying to make Edit view work with DropDownListFor in ASP MVC 5, but whatever I select, the posted value remains the old one. I find that odd because, initially, selected item is the actual model value. And that goes for both DropDownListFor elements I have on the page.

Furthermore, the same logic works on the Create view of the same controller.

Model properties:

```
public List<ProizvodjacViewModel> VendorList { get; set; }
public List<KategorijaViewModel> CategoryList { get; set; }
```

View elements:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProizvodjacID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProizvodjacID, new SelectList(Model.VendorList, "ID", "Naziv"))
            </div>
      </div>

<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KategorijaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.KategorijaId, new SelectList(Model.CategoryList, "ID", "Naziv"))
            </div>
       </div>
```

The controller is not important since the values posted to it are already bad.

What I did discover is that in the Create view, HTML that is generated is just a plain list:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ProizvodjacID must be a number." data-val-required="The ProizvodjacID field is required." id="ProizvodjacID" name="ProizvodjacID" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ProizvodjacID-error" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="1">Gibson</option>
  <option value="2">Hohner</option>
  <option value="3">Yamaha</option>
</select>
```

But in the edit view, a `selected` attribute is also generated:

```
<select id="ProizvodjacID" name="ProizvodjacID" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ProizvodjacID-error" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Gibson</option>
  <option value="2">Hohner</option>
  <option value="3">Yamaha</option>
</select>
```

Controller methods:

```
// GET: Proizvod/Edit/5
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("Edit")]
        public ActionResult EditGet(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.Err = "";
            ProizvodViewModel p = new ProizvodViewModel()
            {
                ID = id,
                Naziv = "",
                NazivProizvodjaca = "",
                CenaOd = 0,
                CenaDo = Int32.MaxValue
            };

            //goes to DB and gets a product(Proizvod) by id
            DataSet ds = DAL.ProizvodDAL.Pretraga(p);

            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

            p.Naziv = dr["NAZIV"].ToString();
            p.Cena = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["CENA"]);
            p.SlikaUrl = dr["SLIKA_URL"].ToString();
            p.ProizvodjacID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PROIZVODJAC_ID"]);
            p.NazivProizvodjaca = dr["NAZIV_PROIZVODJACA"].ToString();
            p.KategorijaId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["KATEGORIJA_ID"]);

            //populates VendorList from DB -- code below
            popuniProizvodjace(p);

            //same, but with CategoryList -- code below 
            popuniKategorije(p);

            return View(p);
        }

// POST: Proizvod/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Edit")]
        public ActionResult EditPost(ProizvodViewModel proizvod)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (proizvod.ListaKategorija == null)
                        popuniKategorije(proizvod);
                    if (proizvod.ListaProizvodjaca == null)
                        popuniProizvodjace(proizvod);

                    int rezultat = 1;
                    string poruka;

                    //updates the product in DB
                    DAL.ProizvodDAL.Izmena(proizvod, out rezultat, out poruka);
                    if (rezultat != 0)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Err = poruka;
                        return View(proizvod);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View(proizvod);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Err = ex.Message;
                return View(proizvod);
            }
        }

private void popuniProizvodjace(ProizvodViewModel proizvod)
        {
            // gets all vendors (Proizvodjac) from DB
            DataSet ds = DAL.ProizvodjacDAL.Pretraga(new ProizvodjacViewModel() { Naziv = "", ID = 0 });
            if (AetFunkcije.proveriDataSet(ds))
            {
                proizvod.VendorList = new List<ProizvodjacViewModel>();

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    proizvod.VendorList.Add(new ProizvodjacViewModel() { ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PROIZVODJAC_ID"]), Naziv = dr["NAZIV"].ToString() });
                }
            }
        }

        private void popuniKategorije(ProizvodViewModel proizvod)
        {
            // gets all categories (Kategorija) from DB
            DataSet ds = DAL.KategorijaDAL.Pretraga(new KategorijaViewModel() { ID = 0, Naziv = "" });
            if (AetFunkcije.proveriDataSet(ds))
            {
                proizvod.ListaKategorija = new List<KategorijaViewModel>();

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    proizvod.CategoryList.Add(new KategorijaViewModel() { ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["KATEGORIJA_ID"]), Naziv = dr["NAZIV"].ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
```

Any advice?

Comment: "But in the edit view,[...]": that's how you set an initial value in HTML for a drop down (ie. `select` element) reflecting that when editing the existing value should be shown.

Comment: Looks like ID for both dropdown is same.

Comment: @Richard But I never explicitly set initial value... model binding did it. So why does it stay that way when I select something else?

Comment: @Prajwal It looks that way because both properties have the same name (Vendor and Category are both separate classes)

Comment: What do you mean its not binding? - The value of `ProizvodjacID` is `1` so the method marks the option with the corresponding value with the `selected` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, initially it works. For every Vendor and Category, the selected value is correct when the View is loaded. But when I select other value, it won't bind. It passes that initial one whatever else I choose.

Comment: What do you mean _For every Vendor and Category_? That suggests your editing multiple objects (in which case your code would not work). You need to give more information about what your doing

Comment: @StephenMuecke my mistake. For every `Product` (the Model passed to the View), `Vendor` and `Category` values are initially set correctly. But that values remain whatever I choose after.

Comment: The show your controller methods (GET and POST).

Comment: @StephenMuecke done. I omitted some irrelevant code, but the majority is there.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

Model `ProizvodjacViewModel`

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> VendorList { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
        var obj = new ProizvodjacViewModel();
        List<SelectListItem> VendorList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
             new SelectListItem() { Value = "Gibson", Text = "Gibson" },
             new SelectListItem() { Value = "Hohner", Text = "Hohner" },
             new SelectListItem() { Value = "Yamaha", Text = "Yamaha" }
        };
       obj.VendorList = VendorList;
       return view(obj);
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VendorList, Model.VendorList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do you have an idea why it doesn't work on Edit when it works on Create? This is not the only place in the app that this is a problem and I would hate to change all the models that I need a list of something to exist :)